# App with Fragments close when orientation change

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

Hi I have an issue with my little App.
So I'm using Fragments. One is a list view, the other just a textView. When I click on a ListView the texView print the Title Clicked.
In portrait i got the ListView and in Landscape the 2 Frag. 
It work fine but when i change orientation and click (fine it's work) and go back and change again the orientation, and click the App Stop working and print me a popup, but i can see in the back that the intent has worked and the textViex changed.

Do you have an idea where the probleme is located. Where i have the most important code it's in my Frag ListView:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    //variable values is an array of string
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values){
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View view =super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            TextView textView=(TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.flatWhite));

            return view;
        }
    };
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
    String item = (String)getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    TextFragment tf = (TextFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.textFrag);
    if(tf != null && tf.isInLayout()){
        tf.setText(item);
    }else{
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TextActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("value", item);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your LogCat output say?

Comment: @BerndKampl java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment has not been attached yet.

Answer (score 0):

When configurations changed during run time such as screen orientation, Android usually destroys application’s existing Activity or Fragment and recreate it.

You have following options:
**Lock screen orientation**

or

**Prevent Activity to recreated**
Another most common solution to dealing with orientation changes by setting the android:configChanges flag on your Activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
```

Or
**Save basic state**
This is the most common situation to save the basic data of your Activity or Fragment during orientation change. You can save Primitive data such as String, Boolean, Integers or Parcelable objects in a Bundle during the orientation change and read the same data when Activity recreated.